# Create a basic webpack setup to output css

Tags: webpack

I'm trying to create a super simple webpack set up to create the css from sass

I have the files:

index.html
entry.js
package.json
webpack.config.js
css
-app.scss

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>

<body>

<script type="text/javascript" src="bundle.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

entry.js:

```
require('./css/app.scss');
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "ls",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer-loader": "^3.2.0",
    "css-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.9.2",
    "postcss-loader": "^2.1.6",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.21.0",
    "svg-sprite-loader": "^3.8.0",
    "ts-loader": "^4.4.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.5"
  }
}
```

webpack.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: "./entry.js",
    output: {
        path: __dirname,
        filename: "bundle.js"
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: [ 'style-loader','css-loader','postcss-loader' ]
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

app.scss:

```
*{
  color: red;
}
```

If I run `npm start` I get the error `Error: Cannot find module 'webpack'`

How do I set this up to output the css from the app.scss file

UPDATE

I installed webpack and now I'm getting the following error

```
Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration.module has an unknown property 'loaders'. These properties are valid:
   object { exprContextCritical?, exprContextRecursive?, exprContextRegExp?, exprContextRequest?, noParse?, rules?, defaultRules?, unknownContextCritical?, unknownContextRecursive?, unknownContextRegExp?, unknownContextRequest?, unsafeCache?, wrappedContextCritical?, wrappedContextRecursive?, wrappedContextRegExp?, strictExportPresence?, strictThisContextOnImports? }
   -> Options affecting the normal modules (`NormalModuleFactory`).
```

Comment: install webpack: `npm install --save-dev webpack`. You are missing it.

Comment: Now I'm getting something completely different - I have updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
module.exports = {
    entry: "./entry.js",
    output: {
        path: __dirname,
        filename: "bundle.js"
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: [ 'style-loader','css-loader','postcss-loader' ]
            }
        ]
    }
};
```